# Implementing an ArrayList and getting individual values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I've been trying to figure out how I could get the values of an array list over the last couple of hours and I just can't seem to find anything that actually useful that can answer my question. I'm trying to get this result:

```
STACK TESTING

4

8

8

9

The size of the stack is: 3

The stack contains:

9

7

3
```

Now I'm able to get STACK TESTING followed by 4, 8, 8, 9, but I'm having trouble getting the actual size of the stack to print the number of items it contains and then print each individual item within the list like above.  Whenever I try to use something in the toString method it gives me an error similar to this "cannot invoke size() on the array type T[]. If I use stack.length its outputting 100 but thats not what I need.  I'm mainly working on isEmpty(), size() and toString()

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Murray_A05Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayStack<Integer> stack = new ArrayStack<Integer>();


        System.out.println("STACK TESTING");

        stack.push(3); // <----- bottom
        stack.push(7);
        stack.push(4); // <----- top 
        System.out.println(stack.peek()); // <--- peeking top so 4
        stack.pop(); // <----- popping off top so its popping off 4
        stack.push(9); 
        stack.push(8); // <---- new final top 8,9,7,3
        System.out.println(stack.peek());  // <------ peeking at 8     
        System.out.println(stack.pop()); // <------ popping off 8 to leave 9,7,3
        System.out.println(stack.peek()); // <------ peeking now at 9 

        int value = stack.size();

        System.out.println("The size of the stack is: " + stack.size());
        System.out.println("The stack contains:\n" + stack.toString());        

    } // End of main method header

    public static class ArrayStack<T> implements StackADT<T>
    {
        private final static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

        private int top;  
        private T[] stack;

        /**
         * Creates an empty stack using the default capacity.
         */
        public ArrayStack()
        {
            this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
        }

        /**
         * Creates an empty stack using the specified capacity.
         * @param initialCapacity the initial size of the array 
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //see p505.
        public ArrayStack(int initialCapacity)
        {
            top = 0;
            stack = (T[])(new Object[initialCapacity]);
        }

        /**
         * Adds the specified element to the top of this stack, expanding
         * the capacity of the array if necessary.
         * @param element generic element to be pushed onto stack
         */
        public void push(T element)
        {
            if (size() == stack.length) 
                expandCapacity();

            stack[top] = element;
            top++;
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new array to store the contents of this stack with
         * twice the capacity of the old one.
         */
        private void expandCapacity()
        {
            stack = Arrays.copyOf(stack, stack.length * 2);   
        }

        /**
         * Removes the element at the top of this stack and returns a
         * reference to it. 
         * @return element removed from top of stack
         * @throws EmptyCollectionException if stack is empty 
         */
        public T pop() throws EmptyCollectionException
        {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");

            top--;
            T result = stack[top];
            stack[top] = null; 

            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a reference to the element at the top of this stack.
         * The element is not removed from the stack. 
         * @return element on top of stack
         * @throws EmptyCollectionException if stack is empty
         */
        public T peek() throws EmptyCollectionException
        {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");

            return stack[top-1];
        }

        /**
         * Returns true if this stack is empty and false otherwise. 
         * @return true if this stack is empty
         */
   //*****************************
   // First one to be implemented
   //*****************************
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {

            return (stack == null);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of elements in this stack.
         * @param stack2 
         * @return the number of elements in the stack
         */
        public int size()
        {

            return 0; // have this set to 0 temporary since I'm getting the error

        }


        /**
         * Returns a string representation of this stack. The string has the
         * form of each element printed on its own line, with the top most
         * element displayed first, and the bottom most element displayed last.
         * If the list is empty, returns the word "empty".
         * @return a string representation of the stack
         */


        public String toString()
        {

           return stack.size;

        }


        }  
}
```

To go along with this, I have three additional files:

File #1

```
public class LinearNode<T>
{
    private LinearNode<T> next;
    private T element;

    /**
     * Creates an empty node.
     */
    public LinearNode()
    {
        next = null;
        element = null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a node storing the specified element.
     * @param elem element to be stored
     */
    public LinearNode(T elem)
    {
        next = null;
        element = elem;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the node that follows this one.
     * @return reference to next node
     */
    public LinearNode<T> getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the node that follows this one.
     * @param node node to follow this one
     */
    public void setNext(LinearNode<T> node)
    {
        next = node;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element stored in this node.
     * @return element stored at the node
     */
    public T getElement()
    {
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the element stored in this node.
     * @param elem element to be stored at this node
     */
    public void setElement(T elem)
    {
        element = elem;
    }
}
```

File #2

```
public interface StackADT<T>
{
    /**  
     * Adds the specified element to the top of this stack. 
     * @param element element to be pushed onto the stack
     */
    public void push(T element);

    /**  
     * Removes and returns the top element from this stack. 
     * @return the element removed from the stack
     */
    public T pop();

    /**  
     * Returns without removing the top element of this stack. 
     * @return the element on top of the stack
     */
    public T peek();

    /**  
     * Returns true if this stack contains no elements. 
     * @return true if the stack is empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty();

    /** 
     * Returns the number of elements in this stack. 
     * @return the number of elements in the stack
     */
    public int size();

    /**  
     * Returns a string representation of this stack. 
     * @return a string representation of the stack
     */
    public String toString();
}
```

And lastly, File #3

```
public class EmptyCollectionException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * Sets up this exception with an appropriate message.
     * @param collection the name of the collection
     */
    public EmptyCollectionException(String collection)
    {
        super("The " + collection + " is empty.");
    }

}
```

Can anyone please explain to me why I'm not able to do anything within the toString(), size() and isEmpty() methods without getting the error pointing to T[]?

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: I was just briefly looking at your code: Array doesn't have the method `size`, so the exception is ok. In `expandCapacity` you are allocating twice the size of the current array, so it's not surprising the length of the array doesn't represent the actual number of elements but you can just use  `top` (the property in your code) instead.

Comment: Please try to post the minimum amount of code required to demonstrate your problem. It'll help people read the question, and it'll help people answer the question.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time I post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you Probably want something like this

```
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {

            return (top == 0);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of elements in this stack.
         * @param stack2 
         * @return the number of elements in the stack
         */
        public int size()
        {

            return top; // have this set to 0 temporary since I'm getting the error

        }


        /**
         * Returns a string representation of this stack. The string has the
         * form of each element printed on its own line, with the top most
         * element displayed first, and the bottom most element displayed last.
         * If the list is empty, returns the word "empty".
         * @return a string representation of the stack
         */


        public String toString()
        {
           int top1 = top -1;
           String finishedString = "";
           for(int i = top1;i >= 0;i--)
           {
            finishedString += stack[i].toString() + "\n";
           }
           return finishedString;

        }
```